# Android studio Gradle is not building the new Jar file

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I just wanted to try the new android lib, so i just added the dependency like this in my new version of android studio. its not at all building the project only.

Below is my gradle file, new lib added is `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`

```
`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "droid.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
}
```

`

Exception is coming in log file as. I'm new to this android studio, its getting tough for me to digg the error, any help please.

```
`java.lang.Exception
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.createBrokenMarkerFile(FSRecords.java:193)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.access$2700(FSRecords.java:136)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.invalidateCaches(FSRecords.java:1617)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.InvalidateCachesAction.actionPerformed(InvalidateCachesAction.java:68)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter$1.run(ActionMenuItem.java:266)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:926)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:236)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:105)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:512)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:44)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:532)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:520)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)`
```

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: Delete added lib from your gradle and try to add it from project structure (ctrl + alt + shift + S), go to dependencies and add the lib. Then Sync project with Gradle files. Hope this will help you!

Comment: Also try a gradle clean. Click on "Gradle" and under "Gradle tasks", double click on "clean". Also instead of `apply plugin: 'com.android.application' try apply plugin: 'android'.

Comment: Here, from SDK manager i have not downloaded the lib, i have just declared in gradle, wound not that be sufficient? ...Clean gradle i didnt try but i created two separate projects and tried, same issue. i guess its related to something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the dependency declared properly. Check the SDK Manager to make sure you've downloaded the Support Library

Comment: Hi, why do we need to download the support lib, gradale must automatically download and include it right?. it wont fetch from server?.